# MongoDB C# Bulk partial update

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have the following code (does not compile currently)

```
public async Task<IResult<bool>> UpdateStock(List<Product> products)
{
    var bulkOps = products.Select(record => new UpdateOneModel<Product>(
            Builders<Product>.Filter.Where(x => x.ProductCode == record.ProductCode), 
            Builders<Product>.Update.Set(x => x.StockPointStocks.ElementAt(-1), record.StockPointStocks)
            )
        {
            IsUpsert = true
        })
        .Cast<WriteModel<Product>>()
        .ToList();
    await _databaseContext.ProductCollection().BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);

    return await Result<bool>.SuccessAsync();
}
```

What i'm trying to do from a given list of products bulk update the `StockPointStocks` and insert where we don't currently have the product in the DB, however i'm unsure how to finish off the second part of the Update.Set or if this is even the correct way of doing this.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public List<StockPointStock> StockPointStocks { get; set; }
    public List<FutureStock> FutureStock { get; set; }
}

public class StockPointStock
{
    public string Stockpoint { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A sample document and the class structure would be extremly helpful when answering the question. Do you want to add the `StockPointStocks` to the product in an array?

Comment: Apologies i've updated with the class structure, i want to replace the current array of StockPointStocks in the database with the parameterized product StockPointStocks without touching any of the other fields in the Product Document

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace the `StockPointStocks` array with the value provided to the parameter, you only need to perform a `Set` on the list property:

```
public async Task<IResult<bool>> UpdateStock(List<Product> products)
{
    var bulkOps = products.Select(record => new UpdateOneModel<Product>(
            Builders<Product>.Filter.Where(x => x.ProductCode == record.ProductCode), 
            Builders<Product>.Update.Set(x => x.StockPointStocks, record.StockPointStocks)
            )
        {
            IsUpsert = true
        })
        .ToList();
    await _databaseContext.ProductCollection().BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);

    return await Result<bool>.SuccessAsync();
}
```

This replaces the property with the new value and leaves all other properties unchanged.

For an upsert, `ProductCode` and `StockPointStocks` are set automatically, but you will also need to set the remaining properties for the newly created `Product` document. To do so, you can use `SetOnInsert`, e.g.:

```
public async Task<IResult<bool>> UpdateStock(List<Product> products)
{
    var bulkOps = products.Select(record => new UpdateOneModel<Product>(
            Builders<Product>.Filter.Where(x => x.ProductCode == record.ProductCode), 
            Builders<Product>.Update
              .Set(x => x.StockPointStocks, record.StockPointStocks)
              .SetOnInsert(x => x.FutureStock, record.FutureStock)
            )
        {
            IsUpsert = true
        })
        .ToList();
    await _databaseContext.ProductCollection().BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);

    return await Result<bool>.SuccessAsync();
}
```

`SetOnInsert` changes the properties only if an insert occurs for an upsert operation.

Please note that you can also omit the `Cast<WriteModel<Product>>()` call.